# Jensen midpoint inequality reference lost

Tags: reference-request, jensen-inequality, convexity-inequality

I have lost the reference of this beautiful gem. Can anyone help me?

Let $I$ any interval, $f:I\to\mathbb R$ be a function and $0<\theta<1$.

**Definition**. —
Let us say that $f$ is $\theta$-*convex* if
\begin{align}
 f\big(\theta x+(1-\theta)y\big)
 \le \theta f(x) + (1-\theta)f(y),\quad \forall x,y\in I.
 \label{conv-reduite}
\end{align}

**Lemma**. —
Let $f:I\to\mathbb R$ be a function and $0<\theta<1$. Then 
 $$
 \mbox{$f$ is $\theta$-convex}
 \ \Longrightarrow \ 
  \hbox{$f$ is $\frac12$-convex}.
 $$

*Proof*. —
Let $m=\tfrac12(x+y)$.
One ''notices''  that
$
((\theta^2+(1-\theta)^2)m=m- \theta(1-\theta)(x+y)
$
so that
$$
m=\theta\big[\theta m+(1-\theta)y\big]
+(1-\theta)\big[\theta x+\ (1-\theta)m)\big].
$$
Applying $\theta$-convexity  *three times*, one get easily
\begin{align*}
 f(m)
&
\le \theta f\big(\theta m+(1-\theta)y\big)
+(1-\theta)f\big(\theta x+  (1-\theta)m)\big)
\\
&
\le \theta^2 f(m)+\theta(1-\theta)f(y)
+\theta(1-\theta) f( x)+ (1-\theta)^2f(m) 
\end{align*}
So we have 
$
[1-\theta^2-(1-\theta)^2]f(m)\le \theta(1-\theta)[f(x)+f(y)],
$
that is to say
\begin{align*}
2\theta(1-\theta)f(m)\le\theta(1-\theta)\big[f(x)+f(y)\big].   
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add `reference-request` to your tags.